# Chating with your microsoft bot framework via Postman

Tags: botframework, postman

I am quite new to Bot Framework and exploring the solutions.

I am trying to use microsoft bot framework in an **android app** (and a python flask app after that) as an API call. For this I want to figure out how to send a message to my bot and receive the answer **via postman**

Right now my bot is up and running on teams and webchat. I am using bot service to make use of the microsoft bot framework. My app is running on Heroku and the bot is hosted on Azure.

[image]

I have checked the direct line channel on bot service, but **this is returning an iframe for a webchat and i would like instead to send my message programmaticly via python, java, etc as an api call** 
[image]

I have also checked stackoverflow question regarding the v3 bot framework and have tried the following :
[How to connect my python bot to microsoft bot connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38560546/how-to-connect-my-python-bot-to-microsoft-bot-connector)

[Send message from Postman to Microsoft Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276389/send-message-from-postman-to-microsoft-bot)

https://pypi.org/project/botframework-connector/

1° I got an access to my bearer token following the second stackoverflow url :

```
{
   "token_type": "Bearer",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "ext_expires_in": 3600,
   "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL***********************************ObNWg"
}
```

2° Then providing postman with the bearer token with this url https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/

and this json raw body  :

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```

this is returning :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Missing token or secret"
  }
}
```

As mentioned I am new to this, so any insights on the above would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok nevermind, the answer I was looking is available on this tutorial : 
https://thewebspark.com/2018/04/15/directlineapi-testing-with-custom-client-and-postman-microsoft-bot-framework/.

It works perfectly on my side.

1) you use your direct line token with `Bearer <token>`, using POST request on https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations.

you get a new token and a conversation_ID

2)Then you use a GET request on https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/conversation_ID/activities

with your new token as `Bearer <token>`
and your json body  as :

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```

That's all!

Comment: You should accept your post as an answer for future reference. :) Also if you end up creating a useful collection to interact with the Bot Framework you can submit it as a template for other people to use! https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman-for-publishers/postman-templates/add-templates/